# Django model.save() not updating model instance

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to update a  handful of fields if the record has been marked as deleted. When I debug, I can see that the values are being assigned in the view, but not being updated in the DB.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

views.py

```
    contact_formset = ContactFormSet(request.POST, prefix='contact')
    for contact in contact_formset.deleted_forms:
        contact = contact.cleaned_data
        print(contact)
        instance = contact['id_cnt']
        contact_id = instance.id_cnt
        contact_object = get_object_or_404(AppContactCnt, id_cnt=contact_id)
        contact_object.deleted_cnt = True
        contact_object.date_deleted_cnt = '2020-11-23'
        contact_object.deleted_by_cnt = 'adeacon'
        contact_object.save()
```

Comment: If the view is wrapped in a transaction, you won't see the db change till the view is finished.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but when I'm running the same code for 'Edits' it's saving and updating the record.

Comment: I moved the Delete code into the Edit function and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Included the `delete` code with the `edit` code.  Seemed to do the trick:

```
    if '_edit_contact_formset' in request.POST:
        contact_formset = ContactFormSet(request.POST, prefix='contact')
        for contact_form in contact_formset:
            if contact_form.is_valid() and contact_form.has_changed():
                contact_data = contact_form.cleaned_data
                # print(contact_data)
                customer_obj = get_object_or_404(AppCustomerCst, id_cst=id)
                contact_form.instance.idcst_cnt = customer_obj
                contact_form.instance.idtrp_cnt = '-1'
                if contact_data['DELETE'] is True:
                    print('delete me')
                    contact_form.instance.deleted_cnt = True
                    contact_form.instance.date_deleted_cnt = '2020-11-23'
                    contact_form.instance.deleted_by_cnt = 'adeacon'
                    messages.info(request, 'Contact deleted successfully')
                contact_form.save()
                formset = ContactFormSet(
                    queryset=AppContactCnt.objects.filter(idcst_cnt=id).exclude(deleted_cnt=True).select_related('idctp_cnt'),
                    prefix='contact')
                if contact_data['DELETE'] is not True:
                    messages.info(request, 'Contacts updated successfully!')
```

Comment: Ah, that's a piece of context that we were missing. And still without knowing the formset and what this is part of, it's hard to see why this fixes anything.